# Use png as a child of mask container in pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have a scene where I scratch some of background. For this purpose I use masks to display scratched things. The problem is that when I initialize the scene I need some shape to be already scratched and then dynamically scratch other background.
As a mask I use container where I add scratched areas so they work fine, but when I add my png shape to this container it displays as a rectangle, not as a shape I need.

[image]

But when I use this png sprite as a mask, not as a child of mask container it displays fine. But in this case I cant scratch other areas of background.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, did you find a solution ?

Comment: @MlleBz unfortunately no. For this purpose I created a polygon from sprite points using 
PhysicsEditor. It will do a job if your png is not too complex